# Xamarin.Android Templates Pack

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community

for the firs time I'm trying to learn Xamarin Android apps

From VS2017 community I did download the "Xamarin.Android Templates Pack "
I did Create a BottomNavigation App and When I try to debug I did get this error.

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'. SingleApp3
    L:\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Androide\SingleApp3\SingleApp3\obj\Debug__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\library_project_imports\res\values-v24\values-v24.xml

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Did you install the Android SDK? Check this [doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/) please.

Comment: no but  I'm going to do. Thanks for the Imput.

Comment: SDK manager was installed. Did used it to update the packages. Now It works. merci Grace.